# Why do I get null as response in angularjs http request

Tags: html, angularjs, http, response

I am using **angularjs** as Front End  and some **Java Spring** application as back end

The web service is **RESTful Web Services**

I should get JSON repose from server .

But the problem is when it is called it does not show anything in html page

```
$http({
    url: "http://melkban24.ir/city/json/2",
    dataType: "json",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}).success(function(response){
    allStates = response;
       $log.info(response);
}).error(function(error){
    allStates = error;
       $log.info(error);
});
```

Every time it goes to error function

Comment: witch angular version are you using? there is some time the sintax changed from `.success` and `.error` to the `.then` format, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http. But it is not information enough to say, what error do you get?

Comment: the version angular version 1.5.5 is used in this project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cross Origin Request Sharing (CORS) is not enabled

[image: Error Screenshot]
Its an API issue. You are trying to request a resource which is not `CORS` enabled. Either try to make the call from same domain (i.e. host angular project on same domain as API) or enable `CORS` on the API Server.

You can find the configuration to enable `CORS` for all the different web servers on the net.

Comment: Thanks but there should be other way to do without chaning server side